# LINQ DistinctBy chosing what object to keep

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

If I have a list of objects and I don't want to allow duplicates of a certain attribute of the objects. My understanding is that I can use `DistinctBy()` to remove one of the objects. My question is, how do I choose which of the objects with the same value of an attribute value do I keep?

**Example:**
How would I go about removing any objects with a duplicate value of "year" in the list `tm` and keep the object with the highest value of `someValue`?

```
class TestModel{
    public int year{ get; set; }
    public int someValue { get; set; }
}

List<TestModel> tm = new List<TestModel>();
//populate list

//I was thinking something like this
tm.DistinctBy(x => x.year).Select(x => max(X=>someValue))
```

Comment: What library did you use to get `DistinctBy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1) and [`Aggregate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=netcore-3.1) (there is no `MaxBy` built-in method in LINQ):

```
tm
    .GroupBy(tm => tm.year)
    .Select(g => g.Aggregate((acc, next) => acc.someValue > next.someValue ? acc : next))
```

Answer (score 1):

User the `GroupBy` followed by the `SelectMany`/`Take(1)` pattern with an `OrderBy`:

```
IEnumerable<TestModel> result =
    tm
        .GroupBy(x => x.year)
        .SelectMany(xs =>
            xs
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.someValue)
                .Take(1));
```

Here's an example:

```
List<TestModel> tm = new List<TestModel>()
{
    new TestModel() { year = 2020, someValue = 5 },
    new TestModel() { year = 2020, someValue = 15 },
    new TestModel() { year = 2019, someValue = 6 },
};
```

That gives me:

[image: result]